# Getting warnings like : The name tf.summary is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Summary instead

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to machine learning and for my project I have to use tensorflow 1.15.2 version in Google colab specifically, I've noticed that I'm getting alot of warnings after trying to run all my codes. How can I get rid of all these warnings? Or should I just ignore them?

Answer (score -1):

Nothing to worry about warnings. You can suppress these depredation messages using

```
from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
deprecation._PRINT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS = False
```